# Network loss after installing Hyper-V

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, drivers

I am running Windows Server 2012r2, after adding Hyper-V my NIC thinks it is unplugged although I have activity lights blinking.

mobo: MSI A88X-G45 Gaming

I'm using the latest Win8.1 x64 (since there are none for 2012r2) KILLER drivers from MSI product page, latest OS updates installed...what could it be?

[http://us.msi.com/support/mb/A88XG45_GAMING.html#down-driver&Win8.1 64](http://us.msi.com/support/mb/A88XG45_GAMING.html#down-driver&Win8.1%2064)

EDIT:
NIC works perfectly before installing Hyper-V and after I remove Hyper-V. Does not work with Hyper-V installed, no other change made.

I believe the network chipset is Qualcomm Atheros AR8161

UPDATE:
I removed Server 2012r2 and replaced it with Win8.1 and then installed Hyper-V. Networking continues to work so conclusion I am coming to is that drivers do not fully support 2012r2

Comment: Do you only have one NIC? During installation of Hyper-V did you configure that NIC to be used only by Hyper-V VMs?

Comment: Single NIC, I opted to not create virtual switch but still same result. Not sure what happens to the NIC during Hyper-V install...does that feature alter something in the background in order for networking to work?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've installed Hyper-V check that your IPv4 service is enabled on your NIC. Although you said you didn't create a virtual switch I've noticed when installing Hyper-V it does seem to reset many of my network settings. When setting up a virtual switch it even pulls the IPv4 from my physical NIC.

Comment: Yes, IPv4 service is enabled/running. I've done multiple restarts and cycled many network related services as well...seems like the "KILLER" chipset is not compatible with Server 2012